# Safari issue with CSS background

Tags: css, background, safari

This code seems to work on everything but Safari.

background:url("/images/nav.png") no-repeat scroll center center / 17px 17px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)

When I erase "/ 17px 17px" then I see my image displayed on that element.  When I look at it in safari web inspector it shows the CSS code as this

background:url("/images/nav.png") no-repeat scroll center center / 17px 17px transparent

Anyone else ever run into something similar to this?  It use to work but then I had to scale the image and that's when the Safari issues came about.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it seems Safari can't interpret size within `background`.

try to add:

```
background-size: 17px 17px;
```

so your css would look like:

```
background:url("/images/nav.png") no-repeat scroll center center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
background-size: 17px 17px;
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PgB7x/), obviously you need Safari browser to see the difference

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
background:url("/images/nav.png") no-repeat center center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
-webkit-background-size: 17px 17px; //webkit support
-moz-background-size: 17px 17px; //Mozilla support
-o-background-size: 17px 17px; //Opera support
background-size: 17px 17px;
```

It work for all browsers.

Comment: -moz-background-size was supported from Firefox 3.6 (Gecko 1.9.2), however this is no longer support from 4.0 onward. I think same goes for others, read: http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/